# Key combinations are not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview and find that key combinations are not working when writing C# code.  For example, I would like to surround some code using the combination Ctrl-K, Ctrl-S, but I get a message on the bottom (by the Ready msg) that says  "The key combination (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-s) is bound to command (Surround With...) is not currently available."  This occurs for other key combinations.  How do I make these combination available?

Comment: All commands available can be customized in the Environment->Keyboard tool

Comment: Some key combinations depend on the position of the cursor or on selection.

Comment: I don't want to customize any commands, I just want the standard keyboard combinations.  I am asking why they are not available.  They worked well in VS 2019 but stopped working when I updated to VS2022.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to do the following to fix the error:

Tools=>Environmrnt=>Keyboard

Select the corresponding programming language in "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme" (for example, if I use C#, choose Visual C# 2005), and then click Reset.

[image]